# What is the google action and dialogflow agent?

Tags: dialogflow-es

We are doing chatbot project using dialogflow currently. I am confused about the relationship between google action and dialogflow agent.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow agent is a chatbot supported via NLP engine. When you create an agent, you can create intents that agents can respond. So, it is a simple text based bot.

Google Action(or Actions on Google) is a kind of platform app for Google Assistant. By building this, you can have an assistant app which works on Google Assistant. It is a chatbot with rich response (such as carousels, basic cards, suggestion chips etc.)

When you create a DialogFlow agent, you can use it in a various platform (such as messenger, telegram etc.). If you integrate it with Actions on Google project and deploy, you will have an assistant app.